# Unexpected Token "+"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm just making a simple calculator app for android in java.

I started getting the error

```
Unexpected Token at "+" 
    public static final int +=0x7f0b0063;
    in the file R.java
```

It's a radio button which chooses + operation, I renamed its id from `+` to `plus` after facing errors, but while building, it always adds the above line and stops everything (error), if I rename it manually to `public static final int plus=0x7f0b0063;` it returns back to `+` while building again

there's another one `public static final int plus=0x7f0b0064;` (64, not 63)

full code:

```
package testapp.myapp.nhk.com.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
//import android.widget.Button;
//import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioButton;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Definitions
    final TextView Nb1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.N1);
    final TextView Nb2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.N2);
    //final Button BuCalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BuCalc);
    final TextView NResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NResult);
    //final RadioGroup CalcRadio = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    final RadioButton PRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    final RadioButton MRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    final RadioButton TRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.times);
    final RadioButton SRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.divide);
    int N1 = Integer.parseInt(Nb1.getText().toString());
    int N2 = Integer.parseInt(Nb2.getText().toString());


    //

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void DoCalc(View view) {

       if      (PRadio.isChecked()) {
           NResult.setText(N1 + N2);
       }
       else if (MRadio.isChecked()) {
           NResult.setText(N1 - N2);
       }
       else if (TRadio.isChecked()) {
           NResult.setText(N1 * N2);
       }
       else if (SRadio.isChecked()) {
           NResult.setText(N1 / N2);
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to rename your resource.

Comment: @SLaks idk how as i wrote that im a starter (but it was removed)

Comment: @SLaks the resource is named `plus` not `+` but it keeps to add the line of `+` in `R.java`(already renamed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rename or edit anything in the `R.java` file, because the file is *auto-generated* whenever you compile/build your project. So any changes you make will be lost on next build.

You have to **rename your resource (file name or variable)** so it doesn't contain invalid characters.

If you did and you continue with the problem, **clean** your project and build again.

Comment: the same problem after cleaning and rebuilding, and the radio button isn't even named +, it's named `plus`

Comment: @NHK have you tried naming it other way?, probably is one of those strange Android behaviors, try naming 'ic_plus.png' or something totally different as 'ic_sum.png'

Comment: Oh well, i saw that those are id resources, but the same applies, probably you can just name it radio_plus.